# PHP Fatal error: Class 'jsonserializable' not found in Unknown on line 0

Tags: phalcon, php-7, ubuntu-16.04, zephir

Ubuntu 16.04
PHP 7.0.4
Phalcon 2.1.x
Zephir

```
$~: php -v
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'jsonserializable' not found in Unknown on line 0
```

When add phalcon.so in php.ini

Comment: Could you please provide output `php -m | grep json`

Answer (score 17):

Somehow I found the answer on and old bug report here:
[Segmentation fault after update to 2.1.x](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/11093)

The problem is that the phalcon extension is being loaded before the json extension, so I guess that you, as myself, added the `extension=phalcon.so` line in the main php.ini

What you have to do is add a file in `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available` called `phalcon.ini` with the line in it: `extension=phalcon.so`

Then you just go and make a softlink that points from  `/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/50-phalcon.ini` to that `phalcon.ini` file, (important to put a number higher than 20 so it gets loaded after the json extension) and that's it!

Repeat the process to any other configuration that you have for php (apache, nginx, etc).